# draw dot as a sound spectrum in bitmap

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I looking into become a sound programmer.

As I could find some sound analyzer would display a nice spectrum of color on bitmap. Which API do I draw a dot shape? Is it circle or line?

Is it possible to resize the bitmap width and height after adding all the dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a graphic representation for audio, you will need to use the SoundMixer class [computeSpectrum()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()) method. There's a use example on the docs.

As for the rest of your question, I'm not quite sure what you're looking for... In any case, you can use the [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) API , which is available on [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) or more generally [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)